# The bean element doesn't accept the qualifier element in xml

Tags: java, xml, spring

I tried to add a  to a  element as follows :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN 2.0//EN"
        "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans-2.0.dtd">

<beans>
    <bean id="A" class="demo.Point">
        <qualifier value="circleRelated" />
        <property name="x" value="0"/>
        <property name="y" value="0"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="circle" class="demo.Circle">
        <property name="center" ref="A" />
    </bean>
    
    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>
    
</beans>
```

I got an error in eclipse saying :

> The content of element type "bean" must match
> "(description?,(meta|constructor-arg|property|lookup-method|replaced-
> method)*)".

After execution I got the exception :

> Exception in thread "main"
> org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException:
> Line 15 in XML document from URL [file:src/spring.xml] is invalid;
> nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 15;
> columnNumber: 38; Element type "qualifier" must be declared.

Comment: Impossible to tell without the full XML file. My guess is you are using an old DTD or schema that doesn't know the qualifier element yet. Then again: it's 2020. XML in Spring went out of fashion more than 10 years ago. Please use `@Configuration` classes instead of XML.

Comment: If you are going through Koushik's JavaBrain  tutorial on Spring at youtube  ... koushik addressed this problem and solved it in the same video.

Answer (score 0):

You need this in your spring.xml file in order work with "qualify" tag (Spring 5+)

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
    <context:annotation-config/>
```